# State not getting updated when calling the related setState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch images from an `Unsplash API`, and then trying to update the images data using `useState` in the following code.

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get(
      "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=l2U-D_PXXujBJoRiCCMCL2ifi_5ZJcK4AC0WH-A2lKk"
    )
      .then((res) => {
        //res.data is printing correct/expected value
        console.log(res.data);

        setImages(res.data);
        console.log("lul");

        //but images array is still empty
        console.log("images: ", [images]); // []
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, []);
```

If I put the images array in the dependency array, then I am able to update the image array, but then fetching is occurring infinitely.

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that you are trying to `console.log` before React has re-rendered. Updating a `state` through the related `setState` is not instantaneous as the [doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-caveats) says:

> The `set` function only updates the state variable for the next render. If you read the state variable after calling the set function, you will still get the old value that was on the screen before your call.

One way to log changes in your state is to add a `console.log()` just after defining it:

```js
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
// It logs [] the first time and then the fetched data
console.log(images);

useEffect(() => {
  Axios.get(
    "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=l2U-D_PXXujBJoRiCCMCL2ifi_5ZJcK4AC0WH-A2lKk"
    )
    .then((res) => {
      setImages(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is invoked asynchronous (though is doesn't return a promise so you can't `await` it).

Keep your `useEffect` as it is now, and in order to print the new value whenever the `images` changes, you can use another `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("images: ", [images]); // []
  }, [images]);
```