# setData under useState not setting data

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a simple crypto ticker app . I am using an api to get details about cryptos and this is how fetching look likes currently.

```
const [ Data , setData ] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      fetch('https://api.coindcx.com/exchange/ticker').then((result) => {
      result.json().then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp)
        setData(resp);
        console.log(Data)
        setLoading(false);
      })
    })
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  },[])
```

I am using interval so that data is updated every 3 seconds.

The problem I am facing is that in the useEffect setData is not setting data. `console.log(resp)` is working correctly but `console.log(Data)` is loggin out an empty array in console whereas I want data and resp to be the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync)

Comment: No. Can you please solve my problem?

Comment: setState happens asynchronously ,so you cant just predict when it gonna happen ,there was callback mechanism in classes for setState method but not in hooks .You can try fitting console.log(Data) in setTimeout for lets say 2000 ms ,assuming it will update in that time

Comment: That's because `useState` is not performed right away. If you will log data in the render function you will see the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, state not getting updated when calling the related setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71004802/react-state-not-getting-updated-when-calling-the-related-setstate)

Comment: check this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately

Answer (score 2):

If you want to console.log your data
You need to use useEffect for console.log, because setstate in async and not sync

```
useEffect(() => {
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  fetch('https://api.coindcx.com/exchange/ticker').then((result) => {
  result.json().then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp)
    setData(resp);
    console.log(Data)
    setLoading(false);
  })
})
}, 3000);
return () => clearInterval(interval);
  },[])
```

and than:

```
useEffect(() =>
{
console.log(data)
}
,[data])
```