# React Native - useState not updating immediatly

Tags: react-native, state

I'm trying to update my state when `onLongPress` triggered.
I'm printing the result right after the setState but it shows nothing (on the first press)
Code:

```
const [pressedImagesm setPressedImages] = useState([]);
...
onLongPress={() => {
          setPressedImages(oldArray => [...oldArray, { [index]: true }]);
          console.log(pressedImages);
}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, state setter not updating the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71004802/react-state-not-getting-updated-when-calling-the-related-setstate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `setPressedImages` does not update the state object (`pressedImages`) directly. Instead, it adds this update to a queue, and the updated state is reflected on the next render of your component.

This is a pretty common React question - there's a lot of helpful content out there that explains it in more detail (such as [this article](https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253)).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const [pressedImages, setPressedImages] = useState([]);
...
onLongPress={() => {
   const cloneArray = [...pressedImages];
   cloneArray.push({ [index]: true });
   setPressedImages(cloneArray);
}}

console.log('Updated pressedImages:', pressedImages);
```