# setState not running in change handler function, updates on next change

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update a state when my date input is changed, and then due to formatting issues update a second state to actually use in my search. This is what my relevant code looks like:

```
const [eventDate, setEventDate] = useState<string>("");
const [searchDate, setSearchDate] = useState<string>(""); 

function handleDateChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        setEventDate(e.target.value);
        setSearchDate(eventDate + "T00:00:01Z");
        console.log(`Value: ${e.target.value}`);
        console.log(`Event date: ${eventDate}`);
        console.log(`Search date: ${searchDate}`);
    }

<div className="criteriaSection">
    <label htmlFor="eventdate">Select date</label>
    <input
        type="date"
        name="eventDate"
        id="eventdate"
        value={eventDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
    />
</div>
```

However, when I change the date in the input field, the states update one behind the other. So my log looks like this:

```
Value: 2022-08-09
Event date: 
Search date: 
Value: 2022-08-10
Event date: 2022-08-09
Search date: T00:00:01Z
Value: 2022-08-11
Event date: 2022-08-10
Search date: 2022-08-09T00:00:01Z
```

Why do I have to update my date three times to get the initial input to fully register? By the time I've changed the date three times, the state that I need is only just registering the first date that I entered. Shouldn't these all run at once as the value is updated?

Editing to say that I changed it so that it's at least only two behind, but still not updating correctly:

```
function handleDateChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  setEventDate(e.target.value);
  setSearchDate(e.target.value + "T00:00:01Z");
  console.log(`Value: ${e.target.value}`);
  console.log(`Event date: ${eventDate}`);
  console.log(`Search date: ${searchDate}`);
}
```

with output:

```
Value: 2022-08-15
Event date: 
Search date: 
Value: 2022-08-16
Event date: 2022-08-15
Search date: 2022-08-15T00:00:01Z
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, state not getting updated when calling the related setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71004802/react-state-not-getting-updated-when-calling-the-related-setstate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might just be a `console.log` error rather than a real state error. `setState()` is asynchronous. This means the result doesn't happen immediately, it's queued up somewhere.

In your console logs, you are outputting the value of the state itself. This value will be lagged by a few ticks.

```js
console.log(`Event date: ${eventDate}`);
console.log(`Search date: ${searchDate}`);
```

If you really want to know whether it's working, console log with the useEffect hook instead.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Event date: ${eventDate}`);
    console.log(`Search date: ${searchDate}`);
}, [eventDate, searchDate]);
```

Comment: That did it! I saw a similar response on an older post like this, but the way you phrased it made so much more sense so I really appreciate it. You're right, just the logs were behind but the actual data was being updated