# Data fetched using axios is not getting populated

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
let UserDetailsUpdatedCard = {};

export default function ProfileDetails() {
  
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:42690/api/users/user-details", {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}` },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.fetchedUser);
        setUserDetails(
          async (prevState) => await { ...prevState, ...res.data.fetchedUser }
        );
        console.log(userDetails);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        toast.error("Failure to Load Profile");
      });
  }, []);
```

This is the result:
[image: Console]
Why are the setUserDetials not getting populated? I tried with setUserDetials = res.data.fetchedUser. It also didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [State not getting updated when calling the related setState in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71004802/state-not-getting-updated-when-calling-the-related-setstate-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing unwanted `async` function while setting the state. `async` function always returns a `Promise`.

Also `console.log` immediately after setting the state, will not show the updated value. Refer: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value

```jsx
let UserDetailsUpdatedCard = {};

export default function ProfileDetails() {
  
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:42690/api/users/user-details", {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}` },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.fetchedUser);
        setUserDetails((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, ...res.data.fetchedUser }));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        toast.error("Failure to Load Profile");
      });
  }, []);

  console.log(userDetails);

  return (<> .... </>);
}
```